# Move Object aroud curve withot deforming

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I have an Object that should simulates a piece of fabric and bend around a bezier curve wenn moved.
On the top of that Object I want to have pieces of wood, that are connected (glued) to the fabric.
My Problem ist that the wood should not deform when bending around the curve[image]

I tried to parent one piece through Vertex(triangle) but that totally deforms it

[image]

The wood piece does not have any modifiers or constrains and the fabric object has only the Edgesplit and the Curve modifier
[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Consider making an empty  child of  3 verts and parent of  wood.

Comment: I uploded the file

Comment: You need to give us the link, I can't see it  ;)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=KkNR5y0x" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/KkNR5y0x/)

Answer (score 1):

You've scaled your plane on the Z axis, you need to apply the scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Scale*) and the child object won't deform:

[image]

Comment: Oh God! Thanks! You saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

add a follow path and select the curve and the animate the offset value